# Passing jQuery reference through Web Worker

Tags: jquery, dom, web-worker

I'm working on offloading some url polling requests to a web worker. To do this, I need to fetch certain attributes from the DOM element of invokation, pass them into a url request, then update the original DOM element with the results. Since multiple DOM elements use this function to fetch updates, I need to pass through `$(this)` or an equivalent unique identifier to ensure the correct element is updated.

I understand from questions such as ["Passing objects to a web worker"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704323/passing-objects-to-a-web-worker) and ["Can I pass a jQuery object to a web worker"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29947630/javascript-how-can-i-pass-a-jquery-object-table-to-a-web-worker) that this is not possible, so I am looking for a means to emulate this.

Here is a rough outline of my code:

```
//main.js
function update(){
    var data = { 'id'     : $(this).attr('itemid'),
                 'filter' : $(this).attr('filter')}
    updatePoller.postMessage(data);
}

//worker.js
this.onmessage = function(e){
    //format params from e.data
    //make GET request to url
    //when done...
    postMessage(req.responseText);
}

//main.js (again)
updatePoller.onmessage = function(message){
    //process response
    //update child elements of $(this)
}
```

As you can see, I don't need to access `$(this)` inside the web worker, but I need the reference once the request has returned in order to update the correct element. Are there any ways to pass a unique reference to a DOM element through a web worker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to uniquely identify an element when you can't use its reference is to use an `id`. Alternately, you could use a `data-*` attribute, but really `id`s were made for this specific purpose.

So (see comments):

```
//main.js
var lastId = 0;
function update(){
    // Assign ID if necessary
    if (!this.id) {
        ++lastId;
        this.id = "__auto" + lastId;
    }
    var data = { 'id'       : $(this).attr('itemid'),
                 'filter'   : $(this).attr('filter'),
                 'elementId': this.id}
    updatePoller.postMessage(data);
}

//main.js (again)
updatePoller.onmessage = function(message){
    // Use the `element` value sent back to look it up by ID:
    $("#" + message.data.elementId).xyz();
}
```

If having all of those automatic globals (since `id` values create automatic globals) bothers you, you could remove the ID when done with it:

```
//main.js (again)
updatePoller.onmessage = function(message){
    var elm = $("#" + message.data.elementId);
    if (elm.attr("id").startsWith("__auto")) {  // auto ID?
        elm.attr("id", "");                     // remove it
    }
    elm.xyz();
}
```

or with less jQuery:

```
//main.js (again)
updatePoller.onmessage = function(message){
    var elm = $("#" + message.data.elementId)[0];
    if (elm && elm.id.startsWith("__auto")) {
        elm.id = "";
    }
    $(elm).xyz();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I managed to pass the `id` of `$(this)` in to the worker, then return a JSON object from the worker with the response and element id